# Xubuntu 16.04 "Software & Updates" - "Other updates" disabled button

Tags: updates, xubuntu, xfce

I installed Xubuntu-minimal-installation 16.04 from a mini.iso. I use the Xfce-session, not Xubuntu-session. In the *Software & Updates* configuration window, at *Updates* tab the *other updates* button is disabled, I don't know why. Any idea how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I run it all the time and I have not seen this yet.  It's a good question.  I am going to ask though, do you have any repositories selected under the Other Software tab?  I don't know if that is the answer, but I am looking to start somewhere in helping you.

Comment: @Terrance I have the _rvm_ repository for _Smplayer_ and the _Canonical Partners_, both without the _Source Code_.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, thank you!  I am going to see if I can duplicate your issue here to help you then.  =)

Comment: I havent forgotten about this question here, but quick question:  Does the command line `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` work?

Comment: Command `sudo apt update` returns `All packages are up to date.`. I wonder witch file in / is relative with these settings.

Comment: `apt update` looks in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and list files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder for 3rd party repositories.  However, the 3rd party repositories can also be added to the `sources.list` file, but the `apt` program looks through that file then the folder by default.  You might be missing some repositories.